# How can I set Map default zoom and position in Google Data Studio?

Tags: json, google-maps, looker-studio

In Google Data Studio I would to set another default zoom level and also the positioning of the map chart with the follow JSON.

How could I proceed?

The JSON:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

From this zoom:
[image: from this zoom]

To this zoom:
[image: to this zoom]

Comment: The posted JSON is the JSON to style the map.  Please see the documentation, the place to change the center and zoom of a Google Map is in the MapOptions object passed into the map constructor, or via other calls to `google.maps.Map` object functions, not by changing the map styling.

Comment: Hello @geocodezip thanks for the answer, but in Data Studio where I have to put this code? In the JSON window for the embeded map?

Comment: I don't know Data Studio and you haven't posted any code that could be used to answer your question.

Comment: There is no possibility to add code in Data Studio for the embeded map. The only way is to edit the JSON that I have posted in the question. @geocodezip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify the region or country in the Google Map Filter in your Google Maps chart:

[image: 1]

That will filter the specific data you want to show and it will also automatically zoom and position the map to that region or country.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. And so, for example, how could I show only center and south Italy?

Comment: First, go to Google Analytics (Audience -> Geo -> Location) and open the "Secondary dimension" tab to include "Region" in the list. That will allow you to see the regions you already have in your map.

Secondly, in Google Data Studio, add a filter as shown in the picture to include "Region" + "In" with the regions to want to include separated with commas (e.g.  "Valencian Community,Madrid,Catalonia").

PD: I have used spanish regions in my example because I don´t know which Regions are available in Google Maps for Italy, but you should see them in your google analytics panel.

Comment: I don't take the data from Google Analytics but from Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Maps in Google Data Studio are automatically adjusted to your data source. If you want see center and south only, you should filter that data in Google Spreadsheet. You could also apply a filter in Google Data Studio in case you had some column in your spreadsheet that will limit the input values. It doesn't seem possible to do it other way as of today.